# Best way to download file apart from ASIHTTPRequest for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, download

I want to download a file and show the download speed. I have used `NSThreads` with `NSData`. The length property is used with `NSData` to show the downloaded file size. However in my case this does not work. I have tried `ASIHTTPRequest` but because it has not been supported anymore, I faced with many problems in current XCode. So I am looking for something that I can use with the latest Xcode and being supported.

So what would be the best way to download so that I can actually have a look at the download speed or downloaded bytes?

Comment: I gather from your other question that `AFNetworking` did not work for you. Here's a [little demo of my own](https://github.com/robertmryan/download-manager) that demonstrates doing your own `NSURLConnection` downloading on GitHub. It demonstrates using `NSURLConnection` to stream a large file from a server to the iOS file system, avoiding the typical problem with many download classes that try to load the entire download file into memory before saving it locally. My rendition streams the file with minimal memory impact on the device. You asked for examples, so maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest checking out [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) whose `AFURLConnectionOperation` has a `setDownloadProgressBlock`.

If you wanted to roll your own I'd check out the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) and the [SimpleURLConnections Sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009245). The latter's `GetController` shows you how to download using [`NSURLConnection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLConnection), streaming right to persistent storage rather than most implementations that load everything into memory before writing to disk (which is useful when downloading large files). I wrote my own little downloader class on the basis of those references, and I think you'll find that `NSURLConnection` does it pretty well.

But I would first suggest that you check out AFNetworking and see if that fits the bill for you.

Answer (score 1):

AFnetwotking is best option,you can refer below link my friend.

http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/

Happy Coding!!!!